SUMIF with do not include part - Excel
I m using SUMIF formula to get the sum of rows which include a specific text, Test. However, I want to sum up only rows which do not include the color Red.
Currently I m using the below formula:
=SUMIF(A1:A6;"*Test*";B1:B6)-SUMIFS(B1:B6;A1:A6;"*Test*";A1:A6;"*Red*")

Is there a better/clearer formula?



Test
1




Test 1 Red
2


Test 2
3


Test 1 Red
4


Test 1 Blue
5


Test 3
6




Try using the following formula, exclude the part you don't need in the criteria itself using wildcard:


=SUMIF(A1:A6,"<>*Red*",B1:B6)


Or,
=SUM((ISNA(TEXTBEFORE(A1:A6," Red")))*B1:B6)


Or, to include the word Test and not Red, then SUMIFS()
=SUMIFS(B1:B6,A1:A6,"<>*Red*",A1:A6,"*Test*")


With multiple criteria to Exclude:


=SUM((ISNA(TEXTBEFORE(A1:A6,{" Red"," Blue"})))*B1:B6)


Or using SUMIFS()+SUM()
=SUM(B1:B6)-SUM(SUMIFS(B1:B6,A1:A6,{"*Red","*Blue"}))


=SUMIF(A1:A6,"Test*",B1:B6)-SUM(SUMIFS(B1:B6,A1:A6,{"*Red","*Blue"},A1:A6,"Test*"))


Instead of hard-coding, its better to use cell references so it becomes more dynamic and one can toggle around whenever a color is required or not:


=SUMIF(A1:A11,"Test*",B1:B11)-SUM(SUMIF(A1:A11,"*"&List[List],B1:B11))



is there a way to include multiples colors?

Yes you can within curly braces! Can you provide one example

Let's say i want to exclude  both Red & Green

Ok, let me take it as Blue as there is no Green, so it will help to provide a proper example to understand!

@Error1004 I have posted, with SUMIFS() it wont be possible since with multiple criteria it takes as a OR() condition and not as AND() condition. use the one i have posted using TEXTBEFORE()

@Error1004 see also posted with SUMIFS()

it s seems that both formulas =SUM(B1:B6)-SUM(SUMIFS(B1:B6,A1:A6,{"*Red","*Blue"}))  and =SUM(B1:B6)-SUM(SUMIFS(B1:B6,A1:A6,{"*Red","*Blue"})) do not included the filtering for word Test

We include that. Since in the context there are all Test, so i have not considered, let me take it as well!

@Error1004 it wont make any difference here you see: =SUM(B1:B6)-SUM(SUMIFS(B1:B6,A1:A6,{"*Red","*Blue"},A1:A6,"Test*"))


The SUMIFS function, one of the math and trig functions, adds all of its arguments that meet multiple criteria

This may be the easiest (sum range ANDing criteria).
=SUMIFS(B2:B7, A2:A7, "*Test*", A2:A7, "<>*Red*", A2:A7, "<>*Blue*")

Do you want to 'OR' matches (for example, "Apples" OR "Oranges") later?
